# When I stop the action 'fly'(moving free in the 3D space), my view jumps. How do I fix this

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

As you can see in the pictures, my view jumps when I end the action 'fly'. I find it annoying, because I'm right now busy with something that requires a lot of precision. I'm not sure if it can be fixed. In picture 1(top), navigation is on. In picture 2(bottom) navigation is off. So, I start the action 'fly' by pressing 'Enter'. I navigate in the 3D space and I end the action 'fly'. The view I have when I'm stil 'flying' differs from the view that I have when I stop the action 'fly'. I haven't tried anything myself and I'm working in Blender 3.0. Besides that, I'm also a beginner in Blender, so I would like a detailed awnser.

[image: Fly on]
[image: Fly off]

Comment: How are you ending the 'fly' action? If you use Esc or RMB the view will jump to where you started whereas using Space or LMB will leave the view in the same position. See the Blender Manual [entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html#id3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem's already fixed. Apparently, I had to use the orthographic perspective. It was probably a bug or something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.